# switch со статистическими константами

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, по какой-то причине я не хочу использовать `enum'ы` и для этого делаю статические поля с константными значениями:

```
class Priority
{
    public static Priority Low = new Priority(1, "Низкий");
    public static Priority Normal { get; } = new Priority(2, "Средний");
    public static Priority High { get; } = new Priority(3, "Высокий");
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Discription { get; }
    protected Priority(int id, string discription)
    {
        Id = id;
        Discription = discription;
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что я не могу в этом случае использовать `switch`... Если я помечу поле, как `const`, то будет ругань на оператор `new`...

Если какая-нибудь хитрая конструкция языка, которая позволит мне сделать задуманное?

Да, можно через if'ы сделать, но они чуть массивные по сравнению со switch...

Comment: `if-else`? Но то что вы делаете, выглядит очень странно, непонятно в том виде, в котором представлено в вопросе. Откуда ненависть к `enum`, какую задачу оно не позволило вам решить?

Comment: Не понятно. Switch работает с вычислаемым выражением после вычисления которого можно сравнивать с чем-то и выполнять нужный блок кода.
А тут какое вычисление?

Comment: @aepot ну он не очень удобен в некоторых сценариях, когда нужно иметь значение некоторое сложное значение, а не значение базового типа.

Comment: Это же просто, этом случае можно использовать `Dictionary<MyEnum, MyDataType>`.

Comment: @aepot можно... Но как-то все равно не элегантно. Я думал, что как-то можно switch заставить работать без доп. телодвижений.

Comment: @iluxa1810, метки switch должны быть известны на этапе компиляции, соответственно, не могут быть никаким объектами

Comment: Нет, к сожалению без констант не получится. А что не элегантного в `PriorityData[Priority.Low]`? У меня похожая система в работе с локализациями данных используется, есть `static { get; }` словарь с такими данными, трудностей не испытывал с использованием. С масштабированием и вширь, и вглубь проблем тоже нет, при желании можно даже сериализовать в json или xml, и хранить не в хардкоде, правда доя большей гибкости, энумератор все равно выкидывается, и используется просто числовойили строковый ключ. Словарь позволяет получить коллекцию ключей отдельно, и итерировать ее. `Priority["Low"]`

Comment: @iluxa1810, а зачем тебе вообще switch, если у тебя уже есть нужные объекты?

Comment: @Grundy допустим, в одном месте нужно специфические сообщения вывести в зависимости от приоритета и это не хочется добавлять в сам класс с приоритетом.

Comment: @iluxa1810. непонятно

Answer (score 0):

Switch требует для проверки постоянное выражение. Предоставьте ему это, если уж так надо Switch (но свичи это плохая идея для чистого кода). При желании если правильно помню, можно организовать enum из которого можно вытаскивать int значение выбранного элемента (в случаях когда для БД требуется int.

```
public enum EnumIdPriority : int
{
    Low = 1,
    Normal = 2,
    High = 3
}
public class Priority
{
    public static Priority Low { get; } = new Priority(EnumIdPriority.Low, "Низкий");
    public static Priority Normal { get; } = new Priority(EnumIdPriority.Normal, "Средний");
    public static Priority High { get; } = new Priority(EnumIdPriority.High, "Высокий");
    public EnumIdPriority Id { get; }
    public string Discription { get; }
    internal Priority(EnumIdPriority id, string discription)
    {
        Id = id;
        Discription = discription;
    }
}

class SwitchPriority
{
    public void main()
    {
        Priority _Priority = new Priority(0, "sdasd");

        switch (_Priority.Id)
        {
            // Low
            case EnumIdPriority.Low:
                break;
            // Normal
            case EnumIdPriority.Normal:
                break;
            // High
            case EnumIdPriority.High:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: в первой строке вопроса: _Допустим, по какой-то причине я не хочу использовать enum'ы_ - в ответе как раз эти enum и предлагается использовать

Comment: На счет БД: EF FluentAPI позволяет настроить преобразование. Главное, что бы тип имел метод получения значения по ID.

Comment: @Grundy, а то что в свичах использовать классы для проверки он желает - вас не смутило ? Априори невозможно. Swith требуется постоянное выражение.

Comment: @IvanG.Zakirov, он как раз и спрашивает можно или нет.

Comment: @iluxa1810 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943398/get-int-value-from-enum-in-c-sharp здесь пример как преобразовать ENUM для БД в INT.

Comment: откуда вообще в ответе и комментариях речь про enum в бд, если в вопросе про это нет ничего?